# segmentation fault on a for loop in c

Tags: c

I'm writing a magnetometer sampling function.

It goes through the cycle as expected, where samplesPerAxis = 33 and MAX_AXES is 3 and MAX is 999

As you can see the segmentation fault occurs after the for loops complete, but the final "end" doesn't print.

```
void createSamplingData(){
    int i, indexOfValue,  numaxis=0, sampling_value ;
    printf("%i %i %i\n", magmin[0], magmin[1], magmin[2]);
    printf("%i %i %i\n", magmax[0], magmax[1], magmax[2]);

    for (numaxis = 0; numaxis < MAX_AXES; numaxis++){
        printf("beginAxis: %i\n", numaxis);

        sampling_value = magmin[numaxis];
        for (i = samplesPerAxis*numaxis ; i < samplesPerAxis*(numaxis+1) ; i++){
            indexOfValue = findIndexOfClosestValue(sampling_value, numaxis);
            printf("%i: %i => %i\t", i, sampling_value, indexOfValue);
            MagSamples[i][0] = MagInput[indexOfValue][0];
            MagSamples[i][1] = MagInput[indexOfValue][1];
            MagSamples[i][2] = MagInput[indexOfValue][2];            
            printf("%i %i %i\n", MagSamples[i][0], MagSamples[i][1], MagSamples[i][2]);
            sampling_value = sampling_value + (magmax[numaxis]-magmin[numaxis])/samplesPerAxis;
        // creates and even range between mag in min in each axis
        }
        printf("end axis\n");
    }
    printf("\nend");
}
```

output i get:...

```
beginAxis: 0
0: 32648 => 263         32648 32760 32916
1: 32656 => 258         32656 32724 32888
2: 32664 => 130         32664 32754 32898
...
29: 32880 => 488    32880 32774 32804
30: 32888 => 469    32888 32706 32822
31: 32896 => 990    32896 32752 32812
32: 32904 => 973    32904 32808 32844
end axis
beginAxis: 1
33: 32624 => 463    32790 32624 32906
34: 32631 => 685    32784 32632 32884
35: 32638 => 652    32756 32638 32926
36: 32645 => 465    32833 32645 32867
...
63: 32834 => 601    32690 32834 32930
64: 32841 => 597    32689 32841 32923
65: 32848 => 627    32690 32848 32914
end axis
beginAxis: 2
66: 32769 => 511    32793 32749 32769
67: 32777 => 512    32785 32755 32777
68: 32785 => 520    32769 32731 32785
69: 32793 => 504    32853 32707 32793
...
98: 33025 => 86 32805 32775 33025
end axis

Segmentation fault: 11
```

What's going on?

EDIT:
samplesPerAxis is defined as

```
#define samplesPerAxis 33
```

Comment: How is MagSamples defined?  I'm guessing the index `samplesPerAxis*(numaxis+1)` is blowing out past the end of allocated memory.

Comment: As you can see, it goes from 0-98, just as expected.   And "end" gets printed without the trailing "\n"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a guess I'd say the fault is outside the function.  The function ends by printing

```
 printf("\nend");
```

Notice there is no trailing '\n', so the "end" will not be flushed until later. Hence you do not see it in the output.  Meanwhile you continue and run into a fault.

Edit:

```
i think you are right. Could you elaborate on how the flush would 
process with the trailing \n?
```

The `printf` function buffers what you send to `stdout` and flushes it (ie sends it to the terminal) when it encounters a newline '\n' (in what you give it).  To force it to flush without adding a newline character, you can use `fflush(stdout);`.

Comment: probably a good guess, as `\n` gets printed - though theoretically this function could be responsible for a later crash

Comment: i think you are right.  Could you elaborate on how the flush would process with the trailing \n?